# MR implementation not working in Hadoop cluster

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce

Decision tree is working perfectly in Eclipse Juno.

But when i tried to run that in my cluster it is showing error.

Folder `"n "` is created in my local disk `/user/sree`

When i tried `hadoop fs -ls /user/sree/n`

Nothing is in n and no "intermediate" files are created in my `/user/sree/n`
why is it so? It is working perfectly in Eclipse.

Any suggesions.

** UPDATE **

I updated my code to

1.Instead of

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("n/intermediate"+id.current_index+".txt"), true));
```

in `Reduce.java` changed to

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(new Path("n/intermediate"+id.current_index+".txt"), true)));
```

2.Instead of

```
fstream = new FileInputStream("n/intermediate"+id.current_index+".txt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

in `GainRatio.java` changed to

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(new Path("n/intermediate"+id.current_index+".txt"))));
```

It is executing,but it is not completely executed.

I am not able to get the final out.
Am i doing anything wrong.

Comment: Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text

Comment: For text it is Buffered Reader right?

Comment: Readers/Writers for text.  Input/Output Streams for binary.

Comment: BUt when i tried in cluster it is not working peter.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Do you mean the current working directory is not what you assumed it was?  Do you know the default directory is the same on all systems and that directory can see the same files?

Comment: When i ran the above code certain files are not created(as there are intermediate results stored in those files for future use) and my job fails

Comment: If you don't get an error while writing the files, most likely they were written.  Are you sure they don't overwrite each other and your reader is looking in the right place?

Comment: Peter my write is not happening:(. only 2 files are written.other file write gets failed.But i am surprised why these 2 files get created and what about the others getting failed.

Comment: Can you show me the error message where the **write** fails?  All I can see is a **read** failing to find the file.

Comment: Peter the error message is with in the REduce block ..so it is not able to see the error message in console. i went through jobtracker there also i am not able to see. I made it sure that something is not working as i traversed through my hdfs , only 1 file is created.so read fail happens because the file does not exits. ie the files are not cretead in hdfs. But 1 file- intermediate0.txt get created in my hdfs.

Comment: Unless you can see the error, you are going to find it very hard to determine why it is not doing what it should.  It could even be failing before it tries to write the file.

Comment: Yes that may be the reason it fails before it try to write into file..But why is it working in eclipse. Any hint how to rectify it?

Comment: Something is different about your environment or inputs.  Either a library is missing, or the expected directory or resource is not available, or an expected input is not right and triggers something like a NumberFormatException or NullPointerException.

Comment: i have been trying to rectify for a long time. but i am not able to do:(

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Is there any alternative way to do Decision Tree?

Comment: If your logging isn't working for you and you can't fix it.  Can you log any exception thrown to your own file?

Comment: Ok i will do and see.But wen we write try catch{...} we will not be able to see in console right?

Comment: I am guessing not.  I would do a try/catch(Throwable t) as high in your code as possible to catch any point an exception might be thrown.  I would write it to the console and a file. I would also add a line to the file to say the block has started and ended with a time stamp like `new Date()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I tried with several alternation like passing the variable as static instead of writing into file...gone through POGO classes. Nothing solved my issue peter.I have been solving for nearly 2 -3 weeks..Atlast i posted the question.But no response :(

Comment: I agree that writing to a file or logging an error shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I have gone through the job tracker UI. Found that for every mapreduce job same intermediate0.txt is formed..I am not getting  the sequence. U may be able to really figure out what is happening :(. If tym pls help me [JobTracker UI](https://github.com/studhadoop/Reference)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the software if you can have every job end up with the same sequence number.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Is that because of coding error :(

Comment: It could be a coding error in version of Hadoop you have but more likely a configuration error.

Comment: Should i recode it in Mapreduce api instead of mapred api. Whether that solve the problem peter....any guessess

Comment: I assume you have checked there is nothing obviously wrong in your code.  The fault is likely to be elsewhere.

Comment: Peter i am a fresher.. I am not sure if i coded in the right way or not

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C45/intermediate"+id.current_index+".txt"), true));
                            bw.write(text);
```

Writes to the local disk and not to HDFS. Thus you have to look for it in your local filesystem.

Comment: Thxs for the reply thomas :) If it is created in my local disk then all the related files should also be created in that right?.I am running my jar file in a Remote machine(cluster). I looked every where in the remote system but could nt find any file related to my program except the folder "C45" is only created in /user/sree. Other files are not created. What should i modify in my code to run properly in cluster? Pls sugest.